# How do I get href attribute value from the given HTML using Python+Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have HTML as shown (modified to make it brief)

```
ht=<a class="title" href="http:/www.myref.com/1235" title="This is link to my ref">This is my ref</a>
```

Now from here, I want to extract the `"http:/www.myref.com/1235"`

```
ht.get_text()
```

gives me only the text part `This is my ref`.

Comment: `ht.getAttribute('href')`   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks, I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in my try.

Comment: Please add more detail like code snippet and error stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ht` is a webelement then,

```
ht.get_attribute('href')
```

should give you `http:/www.myref.com/1235`

Since you are getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

This could mean either

1. `ht` is not a web element.
2. `ht` is not rendered properly.

Put some delay before `ht` and try again with `ht.get_attribute('href')`